# "Duplicate" data from query with offset condition

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I'm working on **Laravel Framework 8.73.2** project with **mysql  Ver 8.0.26-0ubuntu0.20.04.3 for Linux on x86_64 ((Ubuntu))**.

I'm getting wrong data from the database when using the offset condition. On the third data request I get unique data, but on the fourth data request I get repeated data

**third data request, offset = 20**

```
select * from `users` where `users`.`deleted_at` is null order by `created_at` desc limit 10 offset 20
```

| id | name | created_at |
| --- | --- | --- |
| '206' | 'Taryn' | '2021-12-04 23:58:38' |
| '207' | 'Teresa' | '2021-12-04 23:58:38' |
| '208' | 'Arthur' | '2021-12-04 23:58:38' |
| '210' | 'Janick' | '2021-12-04 23:58:38' |
| '209' | 'Ambrose' | '2021-12-04 23:58:38' |
| '212' | 'Katrina' | '2021-12-04 23:58:38' |
| '211' | 'Alexander' | '2021-12-04 23:58:38' |
| '199' | 'Maximo' | '2021-12-04 23:49:56' |
| '200' | 'Herman' | '2021-12-04 23:49:56' |
| '198' | 'Tanner' | '2021-12-04 23:49:56' |

**fourth data request, offset = 30**

```
select * from `users` where `users`.`deleted_at` is null order by `created_at` desc limit 10 offset 30
```

Note that records 199, 198 e 200 are repeated here with the previous request.

| id | name | created_at |
| --- | --- | --- |
| '201' | 'Amani' | '2021-12-04 23:49:56' |
| '200' | 'Herman' | '2021-12-04 23:49:56' |
| '199' | 'Maximo' | '2021-12-04 23:49:56' |
| '198' | 'Tanner' | '2021-12-04 23:49:56' |
| '196' | 'Prof.' | '2021-12-04 23:49:56' |
| '195' | 'Murray' | '2021-12-04 23:49:56' |
| '194' | 'Prof.' | '2021-12-04 23:49:56' |
| '188' | 'Ms.' | '2021-12-04 23:49:23' |
| '184' | 'Alanis' | '2021-12-04 23:49:23' |
| '185' | 'Percy' | '2021-12-04 23:49:23' |

How can I fix this issue and bring the correct data?

**All records**

| id | name | created_at |
| --- | --- | --- |
| '45' | 'Adminis' | '2021-04-14 17:31:30' |
| '147' | 'Amal Cruz' | '2021-11-29 01:40:59' |
| '165' | 'Whitakerg' | '2021-11-30 23:13:05' |
| '166' | 'Dela cruz' | '2021-12-02 23:28:49' |
| '167' | 'Dalek990' | '2021-12-04 18:14:22' |
| '168' | 'Banks2' | '2021-12-04 18:22:32' |
| '169' | 'Walton' | '2021-12-04 18:22:46' |
| '170' | 'Ballard' | '2021-12-04 18:22:56' |
| '171' | 'Jennings' | '2021-12-04 18:23:12' |
| '172' | 'Williamson' | '2021-12-04 18:23:20' |
| '173' | 'Sargent' | '2021-12-04 18:30:02' |
| '174' | 'Nicklaus' | '2021-12-04 23:48:06' |
| '175' | 'Chasity' | '2021-12-04 23:48:06' |
| '176' | 'Malinda' | '2021-12-04 23:48:06' |
| '177' | 'Amie' | '2021-12-04 23:48:06' |
| '178' | 'Nelson' | '2021-12-04 23:48:06' |
| '179' | 'Jaydon' | '2021-12-04 23:48:06' |
| '180' | 'Dr.' | '2021-12-04 23:48:06' |
| '181' | 'Dr.' | '2021-12-04 23:48:06' |
| '182' | 'Mr.' | '2021-12-04 23:48:06' |
| '183' | 'Miss' | '2021-12-04 23:48:06' |
| '184' | 'Alanis' | '2021-12-04 23:49:23' |
| '185' | 'Percy' | '2021-12-04 23:49:23' |
| '186' | 'Josue' | '2021-12-04 23:49:23' |
| '187' | 'Ms.' | '2021-12-04 23:49:23' |
| '188' | 'Ms.' | '2021-12-04 23:49:23' |
| '189' | 'Ezequiel' | '2021-12-04 23:49:23' |
| '190' | 'Filomena' | '2021-12-04 23:49:23' |
| '191' | 'Eldora' | '2021-12-04 23:49:23' |
| '192' | 'Prof.' | '2021-12-04 23:49:23' |
| '193' | 'Dr.' | '2021-12-04 23:49:23' |
| '194' | 'Prof.' | '2021-12-04 23:49:56' |
| '195' | 'Murray' | '2021-12-04 23:49:56' |
| '196' | 'Prof.' | '2021-12-04 23:49:56' |
| '197' | 'Kyra' | '2021-12-04 23:49:56' |
| '198' | 'Tanner' | '2021-12-04 23:49:56' |
| '199' | 'Maximo' | '2021-12-04 23:49:56' |
| '200' | 'Herman' | '2021-12-04 23:49:56' |
| '201' | 'Amani' | '2021-12-04 23:49:56' |
| '202' | 'Jeramy' | '2021-12-04 23:49:56' |
| '203' | 'Mrs.' | '2021-12-04 23:49:56' |
| '204' | 'Stuart' | '2021-12-04 23:58:38' |
| '205' | 'Junior' | '2021-12-04 23:58:38' |
| '206' | 'Taryn' | '2021-12-04 23:58:38' |
| '207' | 'Teresa' | '2021-12-04 23:58:38' |
| '208' | 'Arthur' | '2021-12-04 23:58:38' |
| '209' | 'Ambrose' | '2021-12-04 23:58:38' |
| '210' | 'Janick' | '2021-12-04 23:58:38' |
| '211' | 'Alexander' | '2021-12-04 23:58:38' |
| '212' | 'Katrina' | '2021-12-04 23:58:38' |
| '213' | 'Olin' | '2021-12-04 23:58:38' |
| '214' | NULL | '2021-12-21 00:34:25' |
| '215' | 'Jones' | '2021-12-23 01:23:05' |
| '216' | 'Jonh' | '2021-12-23 01:27:53' |
| '217' | 'Super' | '2021-12-23 01:32:59' |
| '218' | 'Mario' | '2021-12-23 01:35:14' |
| '219' | 'Juca' | '2021-12-23 01:40:16' |
| '220' | 'He' | '2021-12-23 01:47:07' |
| '221' | 'Jon' | '2021-12-23 01:48:19' |
| '222' | 'Vincent' | '2021-12-23 01:50:43' |
| '223' | 'Jaquelyn' | '2021-12-23 01:54:22' |
| '224' | 'Jackson' | '2021-12-23 01:55:05' |
| '225' | 'Sarah' | '2021-12-23 02:02:52' |
| '226' | 'Ryder' | '2021-12-23 22:46:42' |
| '227' | 'Remedios' | '2021-12-23 22:59:03' |
| '228' | 'Brenda' | '2021-12-23 23:03:43' |
| '229' | 'Frances' | '2021-12-23 23:07:12' |
| '230' | 'Raphael' | '2021-12-23 23:08:13' |

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because the records are being sorted by their creation time, and there are multiple records that were created at the same time, “duplicates” can appear. The simplest option would be to include a second column to the sort:

```
 ORDER BY `created_at` DESC, `id`
 LIMIT 10 OFFSET 20
```

This will give you a more consistent response order

Answer (score 0):

You are fetch data by offset. At same time, data is inserted or deleted in this table.

You can order data by id desc, and fetch data with condition(id < smallest_id_from_last_query).

EX:

```sql
SELEC * from `users` where `users`.`deleted_at` is null order by `id` desc limit 10.

id  name    created_at
'201'   'Amani' '2021-12-04 23:49:56'
'200'   'Herman'    '2021-12-04 23:49:56'
'199'   'Maximo'    '2021-12-04 23:49:56'

SELEC * from `users` where `users`.`deleted_at` is null and id < 199 order by `id` desc limit 10.
```